# Witnessing strange surge in RDS aurora mysql RDS

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-rds, hikaricp

I have a springboot based microservice application.

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.26.0"
id "com.palantir.docker-run" version "0.26.0"
id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.13.2'
```

Database is mysql5.7 aurora rds
'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.28'
hikaricp - 4.0.3

I am witnessing one strange surge in cpu utilisation stats on RDS performance insight dashboard is that even when there are no requests on my app server, mysql still shows high cpu utilization.

Here are the screen shots:

[image]

[image]

we can observe from the logs that there are no requests on server but when the connection passes its max life, surge in cpu utilization on RDS aurora mysql:
"connection has passed maxLifetime" -> and the top sql shows set autocommit = 0 is the highest number of queries being fired.

Here are my configurations:

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: catalogue
  profiles:
    # The commented value for `active` can be replaced with valid Spring profiles to load.
    # Otherwise, it will be filled in by gradle when building the JAR file
    # Either way, it can be overridden by `--spring.profiles.active` value passed in the commandline or `-Dspring.profiles.active` set in `JAVA_OPTS`
    active: dev
    group:
      dev:
        - dev
        - api-docs
        # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
        #- tls
      prod:
        - prod
        - api-docs
        # Uncomment to activate TLS for the dev profile
        #- tls
      stage:
        - stage
  jmx:
    enabled: false
  data:
    web:
      pageable:
        default-page-size: 20
        max-page-size: 20
    jpa:
      repositories:
        bootstrap-mode: deferred
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: UTC
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true
      hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true #https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/
      hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
      hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
      hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
      hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy: create
      # modify batch size as necessary
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 20
      hibernate.order_inserts: true
      hibernate.order_updates: true
      hibernate.batch_versioned_data: true
      hibernate.query.fail_on_pagination_over_collection_fetch: true
      hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding: true
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      javax.persistent.sharedCache.mode: ENABLE_SELECTIVE
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
  messages:
    basename: i18n/messages
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  task:
    execution:
      thread-name-prefix: catalogue-task-
      pool:
        core-size: 2
        max-size: 50
        queue-capacity: 10000
    scheduling:
      thread-name-prefix: catalogue-scheduling-
      pool:
        size: 2
  thymeleaf:
    mode: HTML
  output:
    ansi:
      console-available: true

server:
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: true
  tomcat:
    mbeanregistry:
      enabled: true
    threads:
      max: 100
  compression:
    enabled: true
    mime-types: "text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json"
    min-response-size: 1024
  port: 8080

# Properties to be exposed on the /info management endpoint
info:
  # Comma separated list of profiles that will trigger the ribbon to show
  display-ribbon-on-profiles: 'dev'

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "health,info,metrics,prometheus"
  endpoint:
    health:
      probes:
        enabled: true
      show-details: always
      show-components: always
```

---

application-prod.yml

```
logging:
  level:
    ROOT: ERROR
    org.hibernate.SQL: ERROR
    com.pitstop.catalogue: ERROR
    com.zaxxer.hikari: ERROR
  config: classpath:logback-prod.xml

spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true
      additional-exclude: static/**
  jackson:
    serialization:
      indent-output: true
  datasource:
    auto-commit: false
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
    hikari:
      poolName: CatalogJPAHikariCP
      minimumIdle: 10
      maximumPoolSize: 120
      connectionTimeout: 30000
      idleTimeout: 300000
      maxLifetime: 600000
      auto-commit: false
      data-source-properties:
        cachePrepStmts: true
        prepStmtCacheSize: 250
        prepStmtCacheSqlLimit: 2048
        useServerPrepStmts: true
        useLocalSessionState: true
        rewriteBatchedStatements: true
        cacheResultSetMetadata: true
        cacheServerConfiguration: true
        maintainTimeStats: true
  servlet:
    multipart:
      location: /data/tmp
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      spring.jpa.show-sql: true
      hibernate.generate_statistics: true
  liquibase:
    contexts: prod
  messages:
    cache-duration: PT1S # 1 second, see the ISO 8601 standard
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1 # report 100% of traces
```

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: thanks I will share the details tomorrow after running it for 24 hours

Comment: Looking forward to your sharing of data for analysis.